# What is ObjectStreamConstants.STREAM_MAGIC?

Tags: java, serialization, magic-numbers

I refer to [`ObjectStreamConstants.STREAM_MAGIC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectStreamConstants.html#STREAM_MAGIC]) in the interface [`ObjectStreamConstants`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectStreamConstants.html), which is defined in the JDK source like so:

```java
/**
 * Magic number that is written to the stream header.
 */
final static short STREAM_MAGIC = (short)0xaced;
```

What is significance of this magic number, and how is it related to Java serialization?

Is there any particular reason that it is a `short` and has the value `0xaced`? I've tried to find more information, but I didn't get anything that helped me understand better.

Comment: Check out the [Java Object Serialization Protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html).

Comment: If you look at the hexdump of any serialization output (an example is provided in Avi's link), it will begin with `ac ed`, which is `ObjectStreamConstants.STREAM_MAGIC`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got it, however , I wanted to print the "aced". How can I do that? I created a simple class which Implemented Serialization. Then did Serialization using `ObjectOutputStream`. Where can I see "aced".

Comment: @CuriousMind Use this code: `ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos); oos.writeObject(thing); byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();`, and then pass `bytes` to a `byte[]` to hex string converter, which can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java).

Comment: @MultiplyByZer0: Got it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

STREAM_MAGIC denotes start of serialzed content.
You can find more details at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/protocol.html